# Scheduling recursive handlers from an IntentService for retrying http calls

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler, android-intentservice

I am trying to implement exponential backoff for retrying failed http calls by scheduling a thread with `handler.postDelayed(...)` every time my request fail. The problem is that I am doing this from an IntentService which dies after scheduling the first thread so the handler is not able to call itself. I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {2f31b19b} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

My class with the IntentService:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        ......

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        HttpRunnable httpRunnable = new HttpRunnable(info, handler);
        handler.postDelayed(httpRunnable, 0);

}
```

My custom Runnable:

```
public class HttpRunnable implements Runnable {

  private String info;
  private static final String TAG = "HttpRunnable";
  Handler handler = null;
  int maxTries = 10;
  int retryCount = 0;
  int retryDelay = 1000; // Set the first delay here which will increase exponentially with each retry

  public HttpRunnable(String info, Handler handler) {
    this.info = info;
    this.handler = handler;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
        // Call my class which takes care of the http call
        ApiBridge.getInstance().makeHttpCall(info);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        if (maxTries > retryCount) {
        Log.d(TAG,"%nRetrying in " + retryDelay / 1000 + " seconds");
            retryCount++;
            handler.postDelayed(this, retryDelay);
            retryDelay = retryDelay * 2;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

*Is there a way to keep my handler alive? What would be the best/cleanest way for scheduling my http retries with an exponential backoff?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage to using an `IntentService` is that it handles all the background threading for you inside of it's `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` method. There is no reason for you to manage a handler yourself in this case.

Here's a way you could approach this using the `AlarmManager` to schedule the delivery of an intent to your service. You would keep the retry information in the intent to be delivered.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {

    private static final String EXTRA_FAILED_ATTEMPTS = "com.your.package.EXTRA_FAILED_ATTEMPTS";
    private static final String EXTRA_LAST_DELAY = "com.your.package.EXTRA_LAST_DELAY";
    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 10;
    private static final int RETRY_DELAY = 1000;

    public YourService() {
        super("YourService");
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Your other code obtaining your info string.

        try {
            // Make your http call.
            ApiBridge.getInstance().makeHttpCall(info);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Get the number of previously failed attempts, and add one.
            int failedAttempts = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_FAILED_ATTEMPTS, 0) + 1;
            // if we have failed less than the max retries, reschedule the intent
            if (failedAttempts < MAX_RETRIES) {
                // calculate the next delay
                int lastDelay = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_LAST_DELAY, 0);
                int thisDelay;
                if (lastDelay == 0) {
                    thisDelay = RETRY_DELAY;
                } else {
                    thisDelay = lastDelay * 2;
                }
                // update the intent with the latest retry info
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FAILED_ATTEMPTS, failedAttempts);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LAST_DELAY, thisDelay);
                // get the alarm manager
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                // make the pending intent
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                // schedule the intent for future delivery
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + thisDelay, pendingIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simply lets the IntentService you are using handle doing the call in the background, and then schedules the intent to be re-sent each time it fails, adding extras to it with how many times it has been retried and how long the last retry delay was.

Note: If you are trying to send multiple intents to this service and more than one fails and must be rescheduled with the `AlarmManager`, only the latest intent will be delivered if the intents are considered equal according to `Intent.filterEquals(Intent intent)`. If your intents are identical with the exception of the extras attached to it, this will be a problem, and you must use a unique requestCode for each intent being rescheduled when creating your `PendingIntent`. Something along these lines:

```
int requestCode = getNextRequestCode();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
    .getService(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, 0);
```

I suppose you could use your shared preferences to store a request code that increments each time you have to schedule a retry.

Comment: Very nice and logical, thank you! I had to make a small fix by changing the last parameter of getService to 'PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT'